# Can't find instance of 'jQuery.expr[":"]' while upgrading to jQuery 3.x

Tags: jquery

I'm in the process of upgrading from jQuery 1.11.2 to jQuery 3.1.1, using the jQuery-Migrate plugin version 3.0.0.

On every page load, I get this warning:

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.expr[":"] is now jQuery.expr.pseudos
```

The problem is that I can't find the offending code, or any variation of it, in either my code or 3rd party libraries. I did find this example, but I don't think it's the same?

```
$.fn.visible = function() {
  return this.css('visibility', 'visible');
};

$.fn.invisible = function() {
  return this.css('visibility', 'hidden');
};
```

Update 1:
Here's the JS code loaded in a web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>UpgradeJquery</title>
  <script src="/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-migrate/jquery-migrate.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Home#index</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The snippet from my bower.json file that lists the versions:

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "^3.1.1",
  "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
  "jquery-migrate": "^3.0.0"
}
```

At this point I suspect jQuery-UI?

Comment: Show reproduction steps and your [MCVE].

Comment: a quick search of the repo turned this up: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/89af4c292eaa5fc1c83437ca71085264dcbef34a/ui/data.js

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/1773

Comment: I'd say ignore the warning, and remove jqmigrate when done.

Comment: I'll do that for now, and just hope that another plugin doesn't ALSO use the old syntax ....

Comment: @KevinB Is it necessary to remove jquery migrate, what If some other plugins use deprecated feature ?

Comment: @SibashritPattnaik then those plugins should be updated/replaced. But it's your choice if you want to leave the migrate plugin in place.

Comment: You mean It's okay If we keep the production version of jQuery migrate plugin in Prod Environment to have a fall back for any deprecated feature?

Answer (score 2):

Open up the console in the browser, then expand the notice.
Follow the stack trace from the top until you find the first file that isn't jquery-migrate or jquery. For example this issue is in tinymce.js on line 65

```
migrateWarn @   jquery-migrate-3.3.2.js?cache=da924a:102
get @   jquery-migrate-3.3.2.js?cache=da924a:113
(anonymous) @   jquery.tinymce.js?cache=da924a:65
(anonymous) @   jquery.tinymce.js?cache=da924a:91
```

The issue was fixed by changing

```
m.expr[":"]
```

to

```
m.expr.pseudos[":"]
```

Comment: For anyone else who comes here trying to fix migrate issues, the correct replacement syntax is: m.expr.pseudos, not m.expr.pseudos[":"]

Answer (score -1):

[:hidden Selector | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)  has changed it's meaning a little bit. But still works.

Normal programmers are not supposed to touch jQuery.expr..  It is not documented.

Are you using/writing code that creates new selectors? If not, you should not have to worry.

Comment: Like I said, I can't find anywhere in my code or 3rd party code that uses jQuery.expr.  But I still get warnings in my console that it's in use, but no indication of *where* it's used.